# Fixed space between two dynamically sized blocks

Tags: html, css

Trying to come up with a way to have a fixed space (eg `20px`) between two blocks on a single line which dynamically resize to fit that line (`50%` each minus the fixed space between).

I ended up with the [following code (demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/XfStv/):

HTML:

```
<div class="cont">
    <div class="left">foo</div>
    <div class="right">bar</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cont{
    outline: 3px solid #ddd;
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
}

.cont div{
    border: 1px solid #f0f;
    background: #fef;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;    
}

.left{
    left: 0;
    right: 50%;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.right{
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Is this a common or a good way to do it? Are there other or better ways (which work in `IE >= 7`).

Tested successfully in IE8 & IE9, and latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is the proper way to have fixed space between to half-fitted blocks, but maybe later you'll have small issuer with container DIV, because child elements are absolute position and parent - relative, so it will not follow heights of child elements.

for example: http://jsfiddle.net/XfStv/3/

.

**------UPDATE------**

You can also use table property for objects, but it's not supported by IE 7:
[image: Browser Support Table]

here is example of tabled version code: http://jsfiddle.net/zur4ik/ehGRk/

Comment: Yea, but thankfully height is fixed in this case. Otherwise it would be more difficult. (Can't see an obvious solution to that. Tables?)

Comment: you can use also tables version if you want: _see updated answer_.